# Ruby calling method from a variable [value(string)]

Tags: ruby

Ruby calling method from a variable [value(string)]

```
obj.get("GET A")
```

Method get opens a folder and checks the value for 'A'
But if there is no folder I'd like to create it and call the same method again
There is a lot of functions as this, so I created a lambda

```
$s1_exists = lambda do |inp|
 File.open(%Q{session-1.txt}, "w")
 puts "Method called on empty Databse, try again"
end
```

But instead of putting the information I want it to call:

```
obj.get("GET A")
```

Of course I could copy/paste the code for each method but it's bad practice...
I tried somethig like this (in lambda):

```
1. obj_m = inp.downcase.split[0]
self.obj_m(inp)

2. obj_m = inp.downcase.split[0]
self.(:obj_m, inp)

3. obj_m = inp.downcase.split[0]
self.method(%Q{#{obj_m(inp)}})
```

I tried to use "GET" as a method,
I believe, I've tried few more but I can't remember now.
If you'v got any idead pls let me now
Btw. I'm new to Ruby so any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Object.html#method-i-send) or [public_send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @max pleaner
For me worked

```
    $s1_exists = lambda do |inp=0|
        File.open(%Q{session-1.txt}, "w")
        meth_call = inp.downcase.split[0]
        obj = Db.new
        obj.public_send(meth_call, inp)
    end
```